# Save file with google chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new in chrome extension developing. So, I have a content script with a function that track the mouse movement.Can I save the result of function into a file ?? I read a lot and I understand this  "you can't access at filesystem with chrome extension", so it doesn't matter, it's ok another solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If it's so important to store the results in a real file, not just inside `chrome.storage.sync` and show it in the extension popup window, then use [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) and create separate programs for each platform you're planning to support.

Comment: Don't forget the good old "make a text blob, download it" trick.

Comment: It crossed my mind but it's too limited, afaik you can't read it, can't append to it, can't specify a different folder

Comment: Not a single one of those requirements was specified.

Comment: Well, those make sense for logging. For example the file may contain dates and URLs of pages with the distance of mouse movements and click count.

Comment: @wOxxOm The file will contain a set of (x,y) coordinate and the URL of tab where I get it. At the moment the most important thing is save the file with this data everywhere on file system, in the future I will find an another solution.